# How do I create the junit5 maven POM files from gradle?

Tags: gradle, junit, junit5

I'm attempting to build (a fork of) [jUnit5](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5).

```
./gradlew build
```

produces the JARs, but I also need the `pom.xml` files that go with the JARs, so I can use the artifacts using Maven. Changes are there is a `gradle` task configured that does this already in the existing jUnit repo, but which?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Gradle is non-obvious to me ... it is the "maven" plugin.

Invoke:

```
./gradlew install
```

which will:

1. Generate POMs into directory `.../build/poms` with name `pom-default.xml`
2. Copy those (while renaming) and the JARs into the local Maven repository at `~/.m2`.